# Remove shadow shown in borders when invoking Show Desktop command in macOS

Tags: macos

On my MacBook Pro, when I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to show Desktop, the Desktop shows, but with a shadow in the border. If I click on it, it will open the recent app that was open, as shown in the picture:

[image]

Is there anyway to disable the shadow? I want that if I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, I should be able to open the Desktop without that shadow in the border.

Comment: You **do** realize that the shadows are there as a visual cue to indicate you are in a particular Finder *mode?* If I have a lot of windows open I just COMMAND TAB to Finder and COMMAND-N to open a new window and don't have to reveal the desktop because everything I want in the desktop is there in any Finder window.

Comment: is it possible to show desktop without the shadow

Comment: You just asked that. I kind of doubt it (but who knows I'm not all-knowing) which I why I offered my comments on your question.